# "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint

Tags: python, django

We have an application that uses custom login Middleware. We authenticate users from the token. The problem is that when this user wants to change any entry in admin panel, it gives an IntegrityError.

```
insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(567) is not present in table "auth_user".
```

because this user is not in auth_user table, we set it to request.user only while authenticate with our external authentication system.
how we can solve this issue?

Comment: The easiest would be to have your middleware create concrete `auth_user`s.

Comment: yeah, I am trying to find a solution to not duplicate users.

Comment: I wouldn't call it duplicating users. You don't need to copy or sync any other data than the ID...